# contents in list of figures are crossing the border

Tags: table-of-contents

[image]

Please look at the figure above. The contents in the List of Figures are crossing the border and they are not appearing fully.

This is the code that I found in the source latex file.

```
 \newpage
 \makeatletter
 \let \asas \ps@plain
 \let \ps@plain \ps@empty
 \makeatother \large
 \tableofcontents
 %\makeatletter
 %\let \ps@plain \asas
 %\let\asas\relax
 %\makeatother
 %\thispagestyle{empty}
 \listoffigures
 %\thispagestyle{empty}
 \listoftables
  %\thispagestyle{empty}
```

What can be done ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The long entries in your `list of figures` have their origin in the `\caption` command of some `\begin{figure}...\end{figure}` environment. `\caption` has an optional argument, where you can provide a short title designed for the `List of figures` such as `\caption[Short title]{This is a really long,long,long description which should not be in the LOF}`

Comment: The `\let\asas` stuff looks strange. What is your intention?

Comment: removing \let \asas and adding a short title in the caption as mentioned in the second comment helped to replace the larger figure title with the small one.

Comment: But is there a way in which which we can have the larger one ?

Comment: Do you really want to have longer 'titles' in the List of figures?

Comment: I do not need to. Right now, I have changed them to smaller titles. Hence solved the issue. Thank you so much.

Comment: But, lets say, I have a longer title, what can be done to display in a right manner ?

Comment: Without more information, it is impossilbe to tell why the captions overfloat the borders. I vote to close as duplicate.